# System.ServiceModel.FaultException после публикации сервиса выбрасывает исключение!

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, веб-служба

Вкратце: Есть веб сервис(ASP.NET, .NET-3.5) и есть клиент(WinForms, .NET-4.5). У сервиса есть dll-ка для общения с 1С-кой через COM-соединение. Пока не публикую сервис, клиент с сервисом "общаются" нормально(даже в Release). Но после публикации сервиса на IIS сервере, клиент не может обработать ответ от сервиса.

Выкидывает вот-такое исключение: `System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException`

> Дополнительные сведения: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   Серверу не удалось обработать запрос. --->
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Сбой при получении производства
>   объектов класса COM для компонента с CLSID
>   {181E893D-73A4-4722-B61D-D604B3D67D47} в результате следующей ошибки:
>   80070005.

Исключение вылетает на строке подключения COM-объекта к базе!

Comment: Если вы **знаете**, что проблема в COM - зачем вы пишите про FaultException? Зачем вообще кому-то знать, что у вас есть клиент, который не может обработать ответ?

Comment: Добавьте на серверную часть ведение логов, чтобы "поймать" исходное исключение, которое является первопричиной. И задайте конкретный вопрос про серверную часть.

Comment: Предлагаю удалить вопрос, так как он не точный, а ответ автора не содержит решения.

Comment: @Andrew B если перейдёте по ссылке, и ПРОЧИТАЕТЕ, то найдёте решение!

Comment: @ВасилийХмеленко, ссылки со временем могут стать недоступными. Одно из правил этого ресурса - включать в ответ информацию, которая помогла решить проблему, а ссылку оставлять как дополнительный источник. [Справка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), [еще справка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Поставьте галочку рядом с вашим ответом. Вопрос ведь уже решен.

Comment: Через 20 часов - поставлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вдруг кому интересно, дело было в настройках приложения работающего с COM объектами 1С.

эта ссылочка помогла: http://infostart.ru/public/387577/